# Why does this perl script sometimes stop printing after the system function

Tags: perl, printing, system

After i changed:

```
system("recode ISO-8859-1..UTF-8 $csvPath");
if($? == -1) {
    die(" failed\n");
}
```

to:

```
if(system("recode ISO-8859-1..UTF-8 $csvPath")) {
        die(" failed!");
}
```

it works better but still not always.

### Code snippet:

```
print("recoding file to utf-8...");
#`recode ISO-8859-1..UTF-8 $csvPath`;
system("recode ISO-8859-1..UTF-8 $csvPath");
if($? == -1) {
   die(" failed\n");
}
print(" done!\n");
```

---

This doesn't happen all the times. Sometimes it works sometimes not.

If it doesn't works (script doesn't finish in that case) the first print works, but the the second one with "done!" is never printed even if it the external command worked.

Comment: It seems to me that if the script runs to end, the print should happen. Does the script finish? Important information in this context is what OS you are on, and what shell you are using.

Comment: No, the script doesnt finish. The System is GNU/Linux. User has bash shell.

Comment: Well, the `system` call waits for the child process to finish, so it would seem that is where your problem lies. Read the [documentation for system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Comment: Also, I suspect this is more a question for the linux/Unix tag, and recode if there is one.

Comment: @peko, There are three possibilities. 1) The `die` or `print` was executed and you just didn't notice (due to buffering or exception capturing or something). 2) `system` isn't returning because the child isn't ending. 3) The Perl process is killed (such as by a signal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test `if($? == -1)` doesn't make much sense.  `$?` will be 0 if the command succeeded, non-0 if it failed.  For example, if the command did an `exit(1)`, `$?` should be 256 -- at least on Unix-like systems.  And it's probably cleaner to test the value returned by `system()` rather than examining `$@` after the fact.

Try setting `$| = 1;` at the top of your program; this makes your output unbuffered, and might let you see some output your script is producing before it dies.

Print the exact value of the command string before executing it.  If `$cvsPath` is an empty string (or if it's `undef` and you haven't enabled warnings), then you're invoking `recode` with no file argument, and it will read from standard input.  That might explain the behavior you're seeing.

Though this isn't directly relevant to your problem, if `system()` is given a single argument, and if that argument contains shell metacharacters (including blanks), then the command is executed by the shell.  With multiple arguments, it invokes the command directly:

```
system('recode', 'ISO-8859-1..UTF-8', $csvPath);
```

`perldoc -f system` for more information.

And in fact, if a bad value of `$cvsPath` is the cause of your problem, that could have revealed it, since it would pass an empty string as a separate argument to `recode`.  The error message `recode` produces in that case is:

```
recode: fopen (): No such file or directory
```

(the empty file name is shown between the parentheses).

Note that a lot of this is guesswork based on incomplete information.  Posting a small complete program that exhibits the problem would make this a lot easier.